# Callback issue. I dont know why it´s the button disabled and the callback returning null

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

I read a lot of callbacks issues but i can´t find where is my problem. I think is something in the callback function but i don't know. I need a ExpansionTile with a button in the title and different buttons in the children, but all the buttons do the same, sum 1 to a variable.

This is my reusable ExpansionTile.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final Function(int?) callbackFunction;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final int? val;

  ExpTile(
      {required this.name,
      this.children = const <Widget>[],
      required this.callbackFunction,
      required this.val,
      key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ExpansionTile(
          title: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: callbackFunction(val),
            child: Row(
              children: [Text(name), Text(val.toString())],
            ),
          ),
          children: children),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the callback and how I call the ExpTile Widget:

```
int val = 0;

  callback(int? value) {
    value = 0;
    value++;

   

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
          val = value!;
        }));
  }
```

```
int? defense;


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var value = 0.0;
    print(val);
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(
          height: 45,
        ),
        const Center(
          child: Text(
            "Data",
            style: ThemeText.progressFooter,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextFormField(
              decoration:
                  textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: "Name"),
              onChanged: (val) => setState(() {})),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextFormField(
              decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                  hintText: "Tank"),
              onChanged: (val) => setState(() {})),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextFormField(
              decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: "Field"),
              onChanged: (val) => setState(() {})),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 45,
        ),
        ExpansionTile(
          title: const Text("Character"),
          children: [
            Text(Intensity),
            Slider(value: (value), onChanged: ((value) {})),
            ExpTile(
              name: "Defense",
              val: defense,
              callbackFunction: callback,
              children: []
```

The button in the title of ExpTile "Defense" it's disabled and when I open the first ExpansionTile "Character" then

val = 1

I don't know why if I don't tap any callback button and the callback to the widget don´t work because

defense = null

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mistake is with the way you've added the callback here in your build method. You need to use the invoke the function when tapped rather than creating a reference. Just add `() =>`

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ExpansionTile(
          title: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => callbackFunction(val),
            child: Row(
              children: [Text(name), Text(val.toString())],
            ),
          ),
          children: children),
    );
  }
```

EDIT: regarding the button disabled status, please check the callback function that you're passing because a button is set to disabled if it receives null for the callbackFunction. Also it could be the same issue as earlier, where you need to do `() => callback(value)`

Comment: Hi, thanks you, now I have solved the disabled button problem, but the defense variable doesn't change. Should I open another questión?